# What's the point of these "random" subdomains on CDN, etc?

Tags: dns, streaming, cdn

I've noticed a lot when using CDNs (streaming videos, files, etc) you download from a terrible-looking random-looking URL that looks something like `vl-in-f95.1e100.net` or `a184-26-136-74.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com`.

YouTube uses ones like `https://r8---sn-5hne6ner.googlevideo.com/videoplayback`

The thing is: what's the point of these and why are they used? How do DNS records propagate so quickly when generated?

Answer (score 1):

Only akamaitechnologies.com or googlevideo.com is relevant for DNS, the rest is handled in that server's application. It's just another way to transfer a parameter.

Comment: Your last sentence may be correct, but your fist one is not. The subdomain itself matters for DNS, as it could point to a different IP address. For example, they could use it to circumvent DNS caching.